# Are piecewise polynomials $H^1$ functions?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, normed-spaces, sobolev-spaces

The Sobolev space $H^1(\Omega)$, where $\Omega$ denoted a bounded polygonal domain in $\mathbb{R}^d$, is defined as:

$$
H^1(\Omega) = \{ v \in L^2(\Omega): \nabla v \in (L^2(\Omega)^d \},
$$
where
$$
L^2(\Omega) = \{ v: \int_\Omega v^2 d\Omega < \infty \}.
$$

Let $\Omega$ be subdivided into elements $E \mathcal{E}_h$. We define a space of piecewise polynomials as:
$$
V_h (\Omega) = \{ v \in L^2(\Omega): \forall E \in \mathcal{E}_h, v_{E} \in \mathbb{P}_k (E) \},
$$
where $\mathbb{P}_k(E)$ denotes the space of polynomials of total degree $\leq$ k on each element $E$. Is it true that $V_h \subset H^1(\Omega)$? If so, is there a way to formally/informally prove it? Either through a simple example in 1D or functional analysis with some topology work involve? (I don't have a lot of experience with the latter so something simple to understand would be much appreciated!)

Comment: Iff it is continuous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can show that a piecewise polynomial function $v$ must be globaly continuous such that  $v \in H^1(\Omega)$ where $\Omega$ is a bounded polygonal domain:

Let $(\mathcal{E}_h)_{h > 0}$ be a familie of decomposition of $\Omega$ where for each $E \in \mathcal{E}_h$ we have $d(E) \leq 2 h$. We use piecewise polynomial function $v$ such that $v|_{E} \in \mathcal{P}_k$ for all $E \in \mathcal{E}_h$, where
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{P}_k := \lbrace v(\mathbf{x}) = \sum_{0 \leq |\alpha| \leq k}{\beta_{\alpha}x_1^{\alpha_1}\ldots x_n^{\alpha_n}} \rbrace
\end{equation}
denotes all polynoms with degree $\leq k$. We show the following statement:
Let $\mathcal{E}_h$ be a given decomposition of the bounded polygonal domain $\Omega$ and $m \geq 1$. The function $v: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfies $v|_{E} \in C^{m}(E)$ for each $E \in \mathcal{E}_h$. Than $v \in H^m(\Omega)$ if and only if $v \in C^{m-1}(\Omega)$:
We show the proof for $m = 1$. The case $m > 1$ follows from looking at the Derivates of order $k-1$. Furthemore we assume for simplicity that $d = 2$ since the proof works similar for $d > 2$.

$\Rightarrow$: For $i = 1, 2$ we define
$w_i : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ piecewise $w_i|_{E} := \partial_{x_i} v$ for each $E \in \mathcal{E}_h$. Then for $\phi \in C^{\infty}_{0}(\Omega)$
\begin{equation}
\int_{\Omega}{w_i \phi d \mathbf{x}} = \sum_{E \in \mathcal{E}_h}{\int_{E}{\partial_{x_i}}v \phi d\mathbf{x}} = \sum_{E \in \mathcal{E}_h}\lbrace - \int_{E}{v \partial_{x_i}\phi d \mathbf{x}} + \int_{\partial E}{v \phi n_i d \mathcal{H}^{n-1}} \rbrace.
\end{equation}
Since $v$ is considered continuous the integrals over the inner edges cancel each other out and $\phi$ vanishes on $\Gamma$. Therefore
\begin{equation}
\int_{\Omega}{w_i \phi d \mathbf{x}} = - \int_{E}{v \partial_{x_i}\phi d \mathbf{x}} \mbox{ for all } \phi \in C^{\infty}_{0}(\Omega).
\end{equation}
Therefore $w_i$ is the weak derivative of $v$. 
$\Leftarrow$: Let $v \in H^1(\Omega)$. We look at $v$ in a neighborhood of an edge and rotate the edge such that it lies on the $y$ coordinate. The neighborhood shall contain the interval $[\underline{y} - \delta, \overline{y} + \delta]$ with $\underline{y} < \overline{y}$ and $\delta > 0$. Let $v \in C^{\infty}(\Omega)$ then for the function
\begin{equation}
\psi(x) := \int^{\overline{y}}_{\underline{y}}{v(x, y) dy}
\end{equation}
we get with cauchy-schwarz-inequality
\begin{align}
|\psi(\overline{x}) - \psi(\underline{x})|^2 &= \left| \int^{\overline{x}}_{\underline{x}} \int^{\overline{y}}_{\underline{y}}{\partial_{\mathbf{x}} v(x,y) d y dx  } \right|^2 \\&\leq \left|\int^{\overline{x}}_{\underline{x}}{\int^{\overline{y}}_{\underline{y}}{1 dy dx}} \right||v|^2_{H^1(\Omega)} \\ &\leq |\overline{x} - \underline{x}||\overline{y} - \underline{y}| |v|_{H^1(\Omega)}^2 \\
\end{align}
Since $C^{\infty}(\Omega)$ is dense in $H^1(\Omega)$ the inequlity holds for $v \in H^1(\Omega)$. Therefore $\mathbf{x} \mapsto \psi(\mathbf{x})$ is continuous especially in $\mathbf{x} = 0$. Since $\underline{y}$ and $\overline{y}$ with $\underline{y} < \overline{y}$ were arbitary, it is only possible if the piecewise continuous functions $v$ are continuous on the edge.

Comment: I guess it is irrelevant that the derivative is not well defined over the edges since those are sets of measure zero and thus we can split the integral over the elements as you did? What would break if the elements were discontinuous? I am guessing the boundary integral won't vanish, which would mean that $v$ does not have a weak derivative?